# discord.py Pick random user from message reaction

Tags: discord.py

I would like to know how to select a random user from a specific message ID response.

I would like to know how to use the command `.voto <id> <Number of people>` to randomly select users.

I’m Korean and I used a translator

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [Message.reactions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=reaction#discord.Message.reactions) and [fetch_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message)

```py
async def voto(ctx, id, num_people):
    msg = ctx.fetch_message(id)
    winners = []
    total_users = []
    reactions = msg.reactions
    for reaction in reactions:
        users = await reaction.users().flatten()
        for user in users:
            total_users.append(user)
    for I in range(num_people):
        winners.append(I.name)  # Add the name to winners
    winners_msg = '\n'.join(winners)
    await ctx.send(f"{winners_msg}\nHas won")
```

Comment: ERROR Help `reactions = msg.reactions AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'reactions'`